# Can I disable the "non-exhaustive pattern matches" warning only for lambdas?

Tags: haskell, lambda, warnings, ghc

Can I disable the non-exhaustive pattern matches warning only for lambdas?

I like the warning in general, but not for actual lambda literals like this:

```
map (\(x:xs)->...) ls
```

I think this code makes it pretty clear that I expect all the values of `ls` to always have at least one element, and there is no neat way to handle the error case in the lambda. (I guess I could move the pattern match into a `case` statement, but that would just be ugly.)

Comment: Just to let you know, it's generally a bad idea to suppress warnings as a rule of thumb in any language. I realise this may be safe, but other areas of your code may be unsafe, and things may change: you don't want to get caught out in those situations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, but only in GHC 7.2 onwards; pass [`-fno-warn-incomplete-uni-patterns`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html#id3065556) (e.g. in your Cabal file's `ghc-options` field, or in an `{-# OPTIONS_GHC #-}` pragma at the top of your file).

However, this will also disable the warning for pattern bindings, so `let Just x = Nothing in x` won't produce a warning. `case` statements are unaffected.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have such situations quite often? This is a code smell IMHO. I'd like to see some such lambdas and I am quite sure we can make a better version that also handles empty lists quite fine. And in all other cases you might go for a `NonEmpty` list type wrapper.

Comment: The actual context was more complicated: I was wrapping up a Haskell function for use in my own interpreted language as an operator. The way the interpreter works, I am guaranteed that an operator will only ever be called with exactly two arguments. I just used a much simpler example for illustration.

Comment: @Tikhon: I see. Yet you could think about making your types reflect your invariants. Most probably this will lead to clearer and more efficient code. Remember, if you can't prove (with the help of the type system) that your invariant holds in all cases, then Haskell will have to check them at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of `map`, you could write this as a list comprehension.

```
[... | (x:xs) <- ls]
```

This will not produce any warnings. Although, if an empty list *does* show up, this will simply filter it out rather than throw an exception, which might conceal errors. Going the type safe route [as Ingo suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9151872/98117) might be a better option if you're worried about that.

Comment: The map was just an example--in my real code, I'm not using a map or even operating on a list necessarily.

Comment: I'd like to note that I had [a confusion](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/38kl9z/thoughts_on_xlambdado_syntax/crw9y4r?context=3) about list comprehensions and non-exhaustive warnings because the code like `[ x | x' <- x's, let (Just x) = x' ]` doesn't produce a warning with `ghc -Wall`, but the code crashes on the missing patterns. If you do the destructuring on the lhs of `<-`, then the behavior is more consistent, less confusing.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-incomplete-patterns #-}` instead of `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-incomplete-uni-patterns #-}`. And I would recommend using per-file approach instead of putting it into you cabal file as it is generally good practice to keep getting warnings of this kind.

Answer (score 1):

You could write

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
map (\case (x:xs)->...; [] -> error "wut") ls
```

In "wut" you could then describe why that should not have happened.